# package org.slf4j does not exist when updating spring-kafka

Tags: spring, build.gradle, spring-kafka, slf4j, lombok

We are attempting to make some updates to our app.  We are using a build.gradle file and updated our `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka` to `2.8.0` from `2.7.14`.

However, when doing this update we get the following error for code that uses lombok logging :

```
error: package org.slf4j does not exist
```

This is confusing because we did not touch lombok.  Here is the declaration :

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
```

I checked the spring-kafka [website](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.x/reference/html/#whats-new-part) for updates to see if there are compatibility issues, but found nothing. Unsure on where to look for this problem, if anyone could help.  We are using java 17 if that helps.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you moving to 2.8.0? The current 2.8.x version is 2.8.10 (and 2.8.x goes out of OSS support today).

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#learn

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

I would recommend going straight to 2.9.2.

It looks like you were relying on a transitive dependency of the `kafka-clients`...

2.7.x

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)).
+--- org.springframework:spring-context -> 5.3.20
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.20
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.20
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.20
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.20
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.20 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.20 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.20 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.20
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.20 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-messaging -> 5.3.20
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.20 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.20 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-tx -> 5.3.20
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.20 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.20 (*)
+--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.3
+--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.7.2
|    +--- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:1.4.5-6
|    +--- org.lz4:lz4-java:1.7.1
|    +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.7.7
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
...
```

Newer kafka-clients only have it on the runtime class path.

2.8.x

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)).
+--- org.springframework:spring-context -> 5.3.23
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.23
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.23
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.23
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-messaging -> 5.3.23
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-tx -> 5.3.23
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.23 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.23 (*)
+--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.4
+--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.0.2
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I added `implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.36'` to my dependencies section.  This seems to resolved this issue.

Comment: Also, yes I updated to 2.9.2 for spring-kafka